# Venn Diagram Deductive Logic

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Sports Training Academy trains a total 200 students on three different sports, namely Cricket, Basketball and Tennis. Each student undergoes training for at least one of these three sports. The number of students who undergo training for Cricket, Badminton and Tennis are 100, 80 and 70 respectively. What can be the maximum number of students who undergo training for all the three sports?

I've deduced an answer of '25' based on trial and approach method by drawing a venn diagram for these three entities. To speed up an answer, is there any formulaic approach for such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we let $C$, $B$, and $T$ represent, respectively, the number of students training in cricket, basketball, and tennis, then the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) states that
$$|C \cup B \cup T| = |C| + |B| + |T| - |C \cap B| - |C \cap T| - |B \cap T| + |C \cap B \cap T|$$
The quantity $|C \cap B \cap T|$ is minimized if all the students training in at least two sports are training in all three sports, that is, if
$$|C \cap B| = |C \cap T| = |B \cap T| = |C \cap B \cap T|$$
Therefore, the minimum number of students who undergo training for all three sports satisfies the equation
$$|C \cup B \cup T| = |C| + |B| + |T| - 2|C \cap B \cap T|$$
Solving for $|C \cap B \cap T|$ yields
$$|C \cap B \cap T| = \frac{|C| + |B| + |T| - |C \cap B \cap T|}{2}$$
Substituting $100$ for $|C|$, $80$ for $|B|$, $70$ for $|C|$, and $200$ for $|C \cup B \cup T|$ yields
$$|C \cap B \cap T| = \frac{100 + 80 + 70 - 200}{2} = 25$$
as you correctly found.